# Finding table regions with pytesseract

Tags: python, image-processing, python-tesseract

I am currently working on scanned images with Windows 7, Python 3.6 and **pytesseract**. The images contain text and table regions - it looks somewhat like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49300/wrap-text-around-a-tabular.

I want to get the coordinates of the table regions in order to crop the images down to that part. Apparently, `tesseract` defines regions with different properties (*PolyBlockTypes* see https://tesseract.patagames.com/help/html/T_Patagames_Ocr_Enums_PolyBlockType.htm) - but I can't figure out how to get that information with **pytesseract**.

Can anyone help me? I would like to solve this by either using **pytesseract** or another python function.

EDIT: My current approach is

```
pytesseract.image_to_data(image='< ... >', config='-c gapmap_debug=1')
```

The configuration gapmap_debug=1 doesn't seem to have any effect though ... at least I don't get an output. Am I missing something? More configuration options can be found at http://www.sk-spell.sk.cx/tesseract-ocr-parameters-in-302-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect tables in images using tesseract 4.0 or using pytesseract?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626003/how-to-detect-tables-in-images-using-tesseract-4-0-or-using-pytesseract)

Answer (score 0):

try below code, recognize phone number (confidence>70) e.g. [phone number img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFviN.jpg) from img data and save to one special folder

```js
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(image, lang='eng', config='outputbase digits', output_type = pytesseract.Output.DICT)
    text = data['text']
    confidence = data['conf'][len(text)-1]
    phone_number = data['text'][len(text)-1]
    print(image.filename, "  confidence" , confidence , "  phone_number" , phone_number)
    if confidence>=70 and len(phone_number.strip())> 10:
        changeFileName = image.filename
        newName = image.filename[0:len(image.filename)-5] + phone_number +".jpg";
        newFileName = os.path.basename(newName) 
        image.save('./recognize/'+newFileName, 'JPEG')
        os.remove(image.filename) 
        print( "old" + changeFileName +"\nnew"+ newName)
```